# Running a flyway command is simply printing the help and exiting in python script

Tags: python, flyway, aws-codebuild

So I have a Python script that I'm running via AWS CodeBuild. It's using the flyway command line docker container to execute the following command:

```
cmd = 'flyway -user=' + connection_items['username'] + ' -password=' + connection_items['password'] + ' migrate'
os.system(cmd) # I know this is insecure... just trying to get a migration to run
```

What happens is it executes flyway without any of the arguments which just prints the help and exits. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I can't run via the `subprocess` module yet (I'm having path issues)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share buildspec.yml

Comment: https://github.com/allenfisher/stackoverflow/blob/master/fly-py/buildspec.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks more like a shell expansion issue than CodeBuild.

Your buildspec was confusing, I rewrote your buildspec as follows. I hope this helps:

```
---
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.7
    commands:
     - echo "Installing flyway..."
     - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --storage-driver=overlay&
     - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
     - echo "docker run --rm flyway/flyway:6.0.4 -url=jdbc:mysql://db -schemas=myschema -user=root -password=P@ssw0rd -connectRetries=60 migrate" > /usr/local/bin/flyway 
     - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/flyway
     - 
  build:
    commands:
      - echo building...
      - /usr/local/bin/flyway
      - python MigrateDatabase.py
```

Also, I am sure you are already setting the privilege mode to true for the project environment.

Comment: That's a good idea to put the entire flyway command including parameters into the script in /usr/local/bin